# Finiteness of group cohomology

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-groups, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a finite group and $k$ a field whose characteristic does not divide the order of $G$. Then if $M,N$ are $k[G]$-modules which are finitely generated as $k$-module, then
$$\text{Ext}^i(M,N)=\text{H}^i(k,\text{Hom}_k(M,N))=H^i(G,\text{Hom}_k(M,N)).$$
Since $\text{Hom}_k(M,N)$ is finitely generated as a $k$-module, we can conclude that $\text{Ext}^i(M,N)$ is finitely generated and vanishes for sufficiently large $i$ (depending on $M,N$).

My question is, how can we extend this?

The particular case I have in mind are algebraic groups (well besides the case of algebraic groups with finite set of rational points).

Comment: It’s not true that $\operatorname{Ext}^i(M,N)$ vanishes for sufficiently large $i$ when $G$ is a finite group. If the characteristic of $k$ divides the order of $G$ then $H^i(G,k)=\operatorname{Ext}^i(k,k)$ is nonzero for infinitely many $i$.

Comment: @JeremyRickard right, thanks, let me change that.